# Any difference between su -www-data vs sudo -u www-data in docker?

Tags: docker, sudo, alpine-linux, su

My php script runs inside a docker and I need to run it using www-data user, so in my dockerfile's ENTRYPOINT I can either

`su www-data -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/local/bin/php xxx"`

Or

`sudo -u www-data  "/usr/local/bin/php xxx"`

I know general difference between sudo and su, but what is difference when switch to non-root user ?

So far the only difference to me is sudo is not installed for alpine based docker so I need to install it first.

Comment: Do neither of these things.  Switch to `USER www-data`, then set `CMD php xxx`.  You don't generally need `sudo` in Docker and getting it set up correctly can be tricky.

Comment: But in my ENTRYPOINT there are other commands I need to run as root.

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to have a look for [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user):

> Avoid installing or using sudo as it has unpredictable TTY and signal-forwarding behavior that can cause problems. If you absolutely need functionality similar to sudo, such as initializing the daemon as root but running it as non-root, consider using "[gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu)".

So, for your scenario, you could just run the `Dockerfile` with `USER root` which is default, and in `docker-entrypoint.sh` still use root to run your command, while finally use `exec gosu xxx xxx` to fork & replace the old process. A minimal example:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian

RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y gosu; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "show user before gosu:"
id
echo "show user after gosu:"
exec gosu www-data id
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
$ docker run --rm abc:1
show user before gosu:
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
show user after gosu:
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

You can also refers to some opensource image for reference: [redis](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/6845f6d4940f94c50a9f1bf16e07058d0fe4bc4f/5.0/Dockerfile) & [its entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/6845f6d4940f94c50a9f1bf16e07058d0fe4bc4f/5.0/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, especially I didn't know gosu exists. Now I have another question, if it is not about docker, is there any difference between su and sudo to switch to a non-root user? I feel there isn't much difference.

Comment: I guess there are many compare already for this 2 concepts, like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577808/difference-between-su-vs-sudo) as it's not a new concept. For your use, because you call it when you are root, I din't see any difference, but if as a plain user, we may see the difference.

Comment: Also, sudo need change the sudoers, while su no need.

Comment: Many Dockerfiles I see around SO give their non-root user unlimited `sudoers` access, and set their password to an easily-guessable thing, recorded in plain text both in the Dockerfile and `docker history`.  This is at best a negligible improvement in security if you can do anything just by saying `sudo` first.  (Also: https://xkcd.com/149/)

Comment: @DavidMaze but what is the problem with su www-data ?